# C++ How to store object in arrays without them deleted

Tags: c++, class, destructor, temporary-objects, copy-assignment

I want to seek help on this issue I encountered when learning C++. I tried to store objects into an array directly, but realize the objects gets deconstructed right away. I could not figure out why exactly is this so.

```
#include <iostream>

class Thing{
    public:
    ~Thing(){
        std::cout<<"Thing destructing";
    }
};

int main(){
    Thing arr[1];
    arr[0] = Thing();
    int x;
    std::cin>>x;
};
```

Comment: `Thing();` creates a temporary object which is then copied/moved into the array. The temporary object has to be destroyed

Comment: When you get a problem like this also add the copy constructor and the assignment operator so you can see everything that's going in. In general, if your class needs a destructor, it also needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator. This is part of what is often called the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: If you're coming to C++ from C# or Java, a big difference is that C# and Java use heap allocation and garbage collection as default, where an assignment keeps the original allocation, while C++ defaults to local (stack) allocation and copying). Pointers can be used in C++, but without garbage collection they are harder to get right so are mostly avoided.

Comment: Perhaps related: In `arr[0] = Thing();`: Why do you even replace the default constructed `Thing` in the array with a new default constructed `Thing`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this statement

```
arr[0] = Thing();
```

there is used the default copy assignment operator that assigns the temporary object created by this expression `Thing()` to the element of the array. After the assignment the temporary object is destroyed.

To make it more clear run this demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

class Thing
{
public:
    ~Thing()
    {
        std::cout<<"Thing " << i << " destructing\n";
    }
    
    Thing & operator =( const Thing & )
    {
        std::cout << "Thing " << i << " assigning\n";
        return *this;
    }
    
    Thing() : i( ++n )
    {
        std::cout << "Thing " << i << " constructing\n";
    }

private:    
    size_t i;
    static size_t n;
};

size_t Thing::n = 0;

int main() 
{
    {
        Thing arr[1];
        arr[0] = Thing();
    }
    
    std::cin.get();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Thing 1 constructing
Thing 2 constructing
Thing 1 assigning
Thing 2 destructing
Thing 1 destructing
```

Comment: I think it should be _the default move assignment operator_ (since the original `Thing` has one)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo As the destructor is explicitly declared then the move assignment operator is not defined by default.

Comment: Ah, got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't know already.

### Smart-Pointer

```
#include <memory>

// ...

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Thing> arr[1];
    arr[0] = std::shared_ptr<Thing>(new Thing());

    // ...

    // <-- Is automatically deleted around here.
}
```

### Pointer

Not-Recommended;
Using pointer would look like:

```
int main() {
    Thing *arr[1] = {};
    arr[0] = new Thing();

    int x;
    std::cin >> x;

    // WARNING: remember to manually delete.
    delete arr[0];
} // <-- BTW, you don't need semi-colon.
```